# Can only print single copies on GIMP and Image Viewer

Tags: printing

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 fully updated with an HP network printer.  Using GIMP and Image Viewer I can't print more than 1 copy, so if I want to print 20 copies of an image I have to export to PDF and use Evince.  I used the same printer on 16.04 for about 2 years and never had any problems.  I noticed the live CD for 18.04 has the same problem using GIMP has a snap or from the Bionic repos.
I think this is a bug in Ubuntu 18.04.  It also seems to affect the latest release of Linux Mint, but it doesn't affect MX17.  I think being able to print off multiple copies of an image in GIMP is very basic GUI functionality.  When I tested it using a USB connected printer on Ubuntu 18.04 there seemed  to be no problem, so it might be network related.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Whilst I've never printed from `gimp`, on programs where I've wanted multiple copies & the program hasn't allowed it, or I know I want to print quickly (& not wait for programs, then files to load), I print to disk (gimp allows this) then use `lp` to print.  `lp` has an option (-n) to print multiple copies (and you can't beat the speed of ctrl+alt+t & `lp path/file` to print a document in my opinion). There may be a GUI method, but this is my chosen method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think all major applications should be able to print multiple copies.  It seems like very basic funtionality.  I still think typing 2 in the copies field in the GIMP print dialogue box is quicker than printing to file and issuing a terminal command.

Comment: Perhaps for clarity I should add I'm only trying to print multiple copies of a single image in one application using a network printer.  That application is GIMP.